# Removing spaces between colored rows

Tags: tables, color, longtable, colortbl

I have a small tex document below, and I have tried various methods to remove the white spaces between rows, but haven't had any luck yet. Thanks! Here's the document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[left=0cm,top=0cm,right=0cm,bottom=0cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\color[HTML]{F8F8F8}\columncolor[HTML]{000000}}l}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\color[HTML]{000000}\columncolor[HTML]{DDF0FF}}l}
\begin{longtable}{NC}
\texttt{   1 }&\mbox{\texttt{ {\color[HTML]{E28964}def}\hspace{1ex}{\color[HTML]{89BDFF}hello}}}\\
\texttt{   2 }&\mbox{\texttt{ \hspace{1ex}\hspace{1ex}puts\hspace{1ex}{\color[HTML]{65B042}{\color[HTML]{65B042}''}Hi\hspace{1ex}guys!{\color[HTML]{65B042}''}}}}\\
\texttt{   3 }&\mbox{\texttt{ {\color[HTML]{E28964}end}}}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see any whitespace: http://i.imgur.com/mlHs9.png maybe it's your viewer? (Have you tried zooming in/out?)

Comment: If you replace the `\\ ` with `\\[-1pt]` the white space seems to go away. I'll leave this as a comment as it is too hackish, even for me...

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm using Preview on the Mac. In the end, I just colored the entire page the same as the background color using \pagecolor{}

Comment: Is this an attempt to typeset [listings](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)?

Comment: This is actually generated from ultraviolet, a syntax highlighting gem which outputs latex too.

Comment: I tried with pdflatex and xelatex and didn't see any gaps between the rows with either pdflatex or xelatex (tl2010 versions) what versions were you and @PeterGrill using? This is likely to be a back end driver rendering issue. If you are typesetting adjacent coloured panels then even a single pixel out is disturbing if it leaves a gap.

Comment: Ah I see.I'm currently using pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011). Thanks for even trying it out.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I also am on Mac TeXLive2011 (packages updated yesterday), and saw the horizontal lines in both the TeXWorks previewer and Adobe Acrobat. I have seem similar issues, and recall that at some magnifications the lines don't show, zooming in shows them, and zooming in further does not...

Comment: @PeterGrill: I am using Ubuntu and I can't see any white lines, too.

Comment: That's interesting. I guess it has something to do with the TeX Live on the Mac.

Comment: Tested on my Mac (OS X 10.7.3): displays fine. This will be an issue with the PDF viewer or PDF viewer back-end in use.